# Why are my glyph-icons not showing on my navbar (bootstrap)?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4, glyphicons

I am making a navbar for my site.

**HTML**

```
<nav class="navbar fixed-top navbar-expand-lg navbar-dark bg-dark">
    <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Navbar</a>
    <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarTogglerDemo02" aria-controls="navbarTogglerDemo02" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
        <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
    </button>

    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarTogglerDemo02">
        <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto mt-2 mt-lg-0">
            <li class="nav-item active">
                <a class="nav-link" href="#"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-home" style="color:blue"></span>Home<span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link" href="#">Link</a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link disabled" href="#">Disabled</a>
            </li>
            <li>
            </li>
        </ul>
        <form class="form-inline my-2 my-lg-0">
            <input class="form-control mr-sm-2" type="search" placeholder="Search">
            <button class="btn btn-outline-light my-2 my-sm-0" type="submit">Search</button>
        </form>
    </div>
</nav>
```

Yet I cannot see the `glyphicon` for home, in my browser it displays like this:

[image: navbar]

My first thought was that maybe the color was black by default and I couldn't see it hence why I added the `style="colour: blue;"` but it made no difference.

Any thoughts?

Comment: use `font-awesome` instead, I think `glyphicon` support only in BS3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In `Bootstrap 4`, `glyphicons` support is removed, please use `font-awesome`.

For more info, visit https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.4/migration/#components

Example of `Font-Awesome`

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/5.13.0/css/all.min.css">

<nav class="navbar fixed-top navbar-expand-lg navbar-dark bg-dark">
    <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Navbar</a>
    <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarTogglerDemo02"
            aria-controls="navbarTogglerDemo02" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
        <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
    </button>

    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarTogglerDemo02">
        <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto mt-2 mt-lg-0">
            <li class="nav-item active">
                <a class="nav-link" href="#">
                    <i class="fas fa-home" style="color:blue"></i> Home
                    <span class="sr-only">(current)</span>
                </a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link" href="#">Link</a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link disabled" href="#">Disabled</a>
            </li>
            <li>
            </li>
        </ul>
        <form class="form-inline my-2 my-lg-0">
            <input class="form-control mr-sm-2" type="search" placeholder="Search">
            <button class="btn btn-outline-light my-2 my-sm-0" type="submit">Search</button>
        </form>
    </div>
</nav>

<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.slim.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/popper.js@1.16.0/dist/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Nice answer donny!

Answer (score 0):

use:

```
<li class="nav-item active">
    <a class="nav-link fa fa-home" href="#"></a>
    </span>Home <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
</li>
```